# Laravel Fortify - How to generate a two factor secret key?

Tags: laravel

I need to programatically generate a 2FA secret key using [Laravel/Fortify](https://github.com/laravel/fortify) but there is no documentation on how to do it?

On my `User` Model I am `use`ing `TwoFactorAuthenticable`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
```

And TwoFactorAuthentication is enabled in `config/fortity.php`

```
'features' => [
    Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
        'confirmPassword' => true,
    ]),
],
```

I have tried things like these functions:

```
// returns a "Call to undefined method" exception
$user->generateSecretKey();

// returns Decrypt error, presumably won't work without a secret set
$user->twoFactorQrCodeUrl();
$user->twoFactorQrCodeSvg();
```

Has anyone deciphered how to do it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more digging, I discovered the `TwoFactorAuthenticationController` in `vendors/laravel/fortify/src/Http/Controllers` which actually has an example in the `store()` function

It works when I use it in my `UserObserver` like this:

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\EnableTwoFactorAuthentication;

class UserObserver
{
    public function created(User $user, EnableTwoFactorAuthentication $enable)
    {
        $enable($user);
        ...
```

Comment: I got this error `Too few arguments to function App\Observers\EmployeeObserver::created(), 1 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php on line 424 and exactly 2 expected` using the method of @user16536896 can avoid this issue.

Answer (score 2):

From my User Controller...

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\EnableTwoFactorAuthentication;
// Add Two Factor Authentication to this User
if ($request->tfa) {
   $tfa = \App::make('Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\TwoFactorAuthenticationProvider');
   $enable = new EnableTwoFactorAuthentication($tfa);
   $myrc = $enable($user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your setup key like so, using the users two_factor_secret stored in the database:

```
{{ decrypt(auth()->user()->two_factor_secret) }}
```